# Why does the Greek lowercase o look disproportionately bold?

Tags: unicode-math, greek, math-fonts, latin-modern

I'm using `unicode-math` and I've decided I really like the Latin Modern Math Greek letters better than those from other fonts. Unless it's an illusion, the omicron (o) always seems to look disproportionately bold, even when not explicitly bolded. Is there a particular reason for this? I would otherwise use the Greek letters from TeX Gyre Schola Math but there doesn't seem to be a `\symbfsfup` variant, and there too the omicron looks disproportionately bold.

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfont[range=it/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfit/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfsfup/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
\[ 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega 
\]
\[ \symbf{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\[ \symup{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\[ \symbfup{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\[ \symbfsfup{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

**UPDATE:** Here is the MWE using `\omicron` and the resulting output. Newcomers to LaTeX who use the legacy engines (like pdflatex) may not know that the `unicode-math` package defines `\omicron`. Legacy TeX/LaTeX books explicitly point out there is no such command and readers may not know about the added functionality of modern engines (e.g. lualatex) and the power of Unicode.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfont[range=it/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfit/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfsfup/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
\[ 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi\omicron\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega 
\]
\[ \symbf{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi\omicron\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\[ \symup{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi\omicron\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\[ \symbfup{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi\omicron\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\[ \symbfsfup{% 
  \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa
  \lambda\mu\nu\xi\omicron\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi
  \chi\psi\omega\Delta\Gamma\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Modified MWE output]

Comment: you used a latin o not an omicron (`\omicron` or ο) which is particularly noticable here as it means you get the dejavu math character not latin modern

Comment: Wow. All these years I've been thinking there was no `\omicron` command defined so I've never actually tried using it. That solves the problem.

Comment: classic tex fitted everything into a 127 character 7-bit encoding so did not have room for a full Greek alphabet so dropped letters that looked similar to the Latin. Unicode fonts have space for more than 127 characters......

Comment: In case David Carlisle’s explanation leaves any doubt: you weren’t wrong. There isn’t an `\omicron` in LaTeX unless you load `unicode-math`.

Comment: I'm grateful that I've been pushed toward Unicode and `lualatex`.

Comment: @Davislor Okay so I wasn't as silly sounding as I may have thought. Still, you influenced me to move to Unicode for the `mandi` rewrite, which is coming alone nicely thanks to `unicode-math`.

Comment: You might also want to add `[Scale=MatchLowercase]` to your `\setmathfont` commands, or even as `\defaultfontfeatures`. That will solve the problem of the Latin and Greek letters having noticeably different x-heights.

Comment: @Davislor Let me read the docs to see if I can understand what those do, then I'll experiment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used a latin `o` not an omicron (`\omicron`) which is particularly noticeable here as it means you get the dejavu math character not latin modern.

`\omicron` is defined in `unicode-math`.  It did not exist in classic TeX, which was limited to 127-character 7-bit encoding, so omitted definitions for anything that looked the same in both Latin and Greek.

Comment: note I rejected the edit as the font is DejaVu Math, dejavu math would work in fontspec   déjà vu math  may have fancier accents but it is not the font name.